# Using the LIMIT statement in a SQLite query

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a query that selects rows in a `ListView` without having a limit. But now that I have implemented a `SharedPreferences` that the user can select how much rows will be displayed in the `ListView`, my SQLite query doesn't work. I'm passing the argument this way:

```
return wDb.query(TABELANOME, new String[] {IDTIT, TAREFATIT, SUMARIOTIT}, CONCLUIDOTIT + "=1", null, null, null, null, "LIMIT='" + limite + "'");
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The equals (`=`) operator is not used with the `LIMIT` clause. Remove it.

Here's an example `LIMIT` query:

```
SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY somethingelse LIMIT 5, 10
```

Or:

```
SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY somethingelse LIMIT 10
```

In your case, the correct statement would be:

```
return wDb.query(TABELANOME, new String[] {IDTIT, TAREFATIT, SUMARIOTIT}, CONCLUIDOTIT + "=1", null, null, null, null, String.valueOf(limite));
```

Take a look here at the SQLite select syntax: http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#select-stmt

This image is rather useful: http://www.sqlite.org/images/syntax/select-stmt.gif

Comment: how about `"5, 10"` Clause? or `LIMIT 3 OFFSET 2`

Answer (score 4):

For anyone stumbling across this answer looking for a way to use a `LIMIT` clause with an `OFFSET`, I found out from [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5318) that Android uses the following regex to parse the limit clause of a query:

From `<framework/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.java>`

> LIMIT clause is checked with following sLimitPattern.

```
private static final Pattern sLimitPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*\\d+\\s*(,\\s*\\d+\\s*)?");
```

Note that the regex does accept the format `offsetNumber,limitNumber` even though it doesn't accept the `OFFSET` statement directly.

Answer (score -1):

Due to this bug which also doesn't allow for negative limits

> 8,-1

I had to use this workaround

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
builder.setTables(table);
String query = builder.buildQuery(projection, selection, null, null, null, sortOrder, null);
query+=" LIMIT 8,-1";
```