# Retrieve group of data from database

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

How to get a group of data stored in database and view them in custom list-view?

For example, I have stored 48 item in my database and want to retrieve only 12 of them each time.
Can anybody tell me how to do that?

Comment: Which database are you going to use

Comment: `costume list-view`? What is that?

Comment: @ :Mohsin Shaikh : I am using a database using sqllite I have created.

Comment: @gunar: the costume list view in android which is extends from base adapter.

Comment: Is that a public API? Or it belongs to your project? ... Looks like it was a typo ...

Comment: The original list-view displays only a text view . If anybody want to display more than that say an image or two text view ,his list view called costume list view and it is differ depends on the purpose of the list.

Comment: Custom is different than Costume; stop using that, you're hilarious! If you want to customize your ListView, then there are a dozen of articles on how to do that. But you need to consider that you asked a specific question and we're trying to provide an answer for that, nothing else included :)

Comment: Sorry I meant to use Custom but the editor correct it to Costume

Answer (score 3):

You may use the SQLite [`LIMIT`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html). Here is [related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497677/using-the-limit-statement-in-a-sqlite-query) that discusses that.