# Stop at first match in a sqlite query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 database worth 4GB and 400k rows. The id column is a consecutive number starting at 1. If I query the following

```
select * from game where id = 1
```

After printing the first match the query continues until it reach the 400k row, thus taking a few seconds to finish the query.

How do I make the query stop at the first match?

Or how do I go directly to specific row since id and rowcount are the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the LIMIT statement in a SQLite query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497677/using-the-limit-statement-in-a-sqlite-query)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just add a `LIMIT 1` to your query:

```
SELECT * FROM game WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1;
```