# fetch only 20 rows from server with setOnScrollListener

Tags: android

Its the first time I am using onscroll listener. My problem is how to fetch 20 new rows every time I scroll down ?.

I understand when I scroll down the grid view this code will be executed.

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                             int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
            this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
            this.totalItem = totalItemCount;

            if ((totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + 20)) {
               // the below when executed will get all the rows ,I only need 20 rows
             handler.execute().get();

            }
        }
```

this is my code

```
// the load more in the grid view, fetch new images.
mGridView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    private int currentVisibleItemCount;
    private int currentScrollState;
    private int currentFirstVisibleItem;
    private int totalItem;
    private LinearLayout lBelow;

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
        this.isScrollCompleted();
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
        this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
        this.totalItem = totalItemCount;

        if ((totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + 20)) {
           // load new 20 row but how to do that

        }
    }

    private void isScrollCompleted() {
        if (totalItem - currentFirstVisibleItem == currentVisibleItemCount
                && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            Log.d("a", "poooppii");

        }
    }

    ;
});
```

this is where the connection happens

```
 protected void showList(){
        try {

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
            System.out.println("Length:"+peoples.length());
            int J_length=peoples.length()-1;


            jsonObj= peoples.getJSONObject(J_length);


                Listitem = new ArrayList<Listitem>();

                for (int i = 0; i < peoples.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String url = c.getString("url");

                    int intid = 0;
                    try {
                        intid = Integer.parseInt(id.toString());
                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
                    }

                    Listitem.add(new Listitem(id, url));
                    System.out.println(Listitem);
                }
            //}
            if (mListener != null)
                  mListener.myMethod(Listitem);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: why you are not using adapter instead of scroll listeners. I recommend adapter, because here this problem can be solved very easily and you will also get better experience.

Comment: can you please me show an example of how using it on an adapter ?

Comment: I have posted my working code for the similar problem solving with the help of adapter, hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an working code, Kindly modify as per your use -

Let assume following is your model -

```
public class MyModel {
    String name;
}
```

You need one interface -

```
public interface PagingListener<T> {
    void onItemUpdate(ArrayList<T> allData);
}
```

Design your adapter like this -

```
public class CouponsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CouponsAdapter.CouponHolder> implements View.OnClickListener, PagingListener<MyModel> {
    private final static int TYPE_LOADING = 0;
    private final static int TYPE_DATA = 1;
    private FragmentActivity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private PagingRequestHandler<MyModel> pagingRequestHandler;
    private ArrayList<MyModel> data = null;

    public CouponsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        this.data = new ArrayList<>();
        this.pagingRequestHandler = new PagingRequestHandler<>(data, this);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position >= data.size() ? TYPE_LOADING : TYPE_DATA;
    }

    @Override
    public CouponHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        if (viewType == TYPE_DATA) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_coupons_card_block, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_drawer_payment_loading, parent, false);
        }
        return new CouponHolder(view, viewType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CouponHolder holder, int position) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_DATA) {
            //Bind your view here
        }
        pagingRequestHandler.checkAndMakeRequestForMoreData(position); //Will check and make request
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size() + (pagingRequestHandler.isNoMoreDataLeft() ? 0 : 1); // If no data then it will return 1 to show loading
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemUpdate(ArrayList<MyModel> allData) {
        this.data = allData; // will update data with updated content
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


    public class CouponHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public CouponHolder(View itemView, int itemType) {
            super(itemView);
            if (itemType == TYPE_DATA) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now this is the paging request handler, that will keep track on page number and will make request for next page -

```
public class PagingRequestHandler<T> {
    public static final int PAGE_SIZE = 10;
    private final PagingListener listener;
    private final ArrayList<MyModel> arrayList;
    private final String url = "Your Url here";
    private boolean noMoreDataLeft;
    private int pagingIndex = 0;
    private boolean requestGoingOn;


    public PagingRequestHandler(ArrayList<MyModel> data, PagingListener<MyModel> listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.arrayList = data;
        fetchMoreData();

    }

    private void fetchMoreData() {
        requestGoingOn = true;
        Call<MyModel[]> getCoupons = Utils.getRetrofit().getCoupons(url + "/" + pagingIndex); // I am using retrofit for network call, you can use your own
        getCoupons.enqueue(new Callback<MyModel[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<MyModel[]> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                try {
                    requestGoingOn = false;
                    MyModel[] couponModelDses = response.body();
                    if (couponModelDses != null) {
                        for (MyModel couponModelDse : couponModelDses) {
                            arrayList.add(couponModelDse);
                        }
                        if (couponModelDses.length < PAGE_SIZE)
                            noMoreDataLeft = true;
                        listener.onItemUpdate(arrayList);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                requestGoingOn = false;
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isNoMoreDataLeft() {
        return noMoreDataLeft;
    }

    public void checkAndMakeRequestForMoreData(int position) {
        if (!noMoreDataLeft && !requestGoingOn && position > (PAGE_SIZE * pagingIndex)) {
            if ((position % PAGE_SIZE) > (int) (PAGE_SIZE * .7)) {
                pagingIndex++;
                fetchMoreData();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**How it works -** The adapter is initialising the Handler, which make network call for first time. The adapter now calls handler api to check if 70% of page is scrolled on every onBind. Now if 70% of data has been shown then it makes network call againe and makes a variable called requestGoingOn true, so you can show a loader in list. Wher request completed the handler is adding data to the arraylist and updating adapter by calling the callback `onItemUpdate`.

Hope it will help, please let me know if you need further assistance :)

Comment: still not yet i was busy lately, tomorow i will check it thanks you

Comment: helllo you there ?

Comment: Yes, need any help?

Comment: can you please post to me the xml for the view? I am testing your code

Comment: You can use your own xml if it is type data, in case of loading just put a circular progress bar with text loading in a linear layout. Let me know if you still want it :)

Comment: well still reading your code , I noticed your using connection with retrofit `  public void onResponse(Response<MyModel[]> response, Retrofit retrofit) {` can you give the dependecy to put on gradle ? I usealy use okhttp connection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116272/discussion-between-neo-and-moudiz).

Answer (score 5):

You need to maintain `base` and `limit` for data load. Initialize your base and limit variable.

```
int base = 0, limit = 20;
```

Increase your `base` variable whenever loading new items.

```
base = base + limit;
handler.execute().get();
```

Pass `base` and `limit` variable in your `API` call, so that you can use it in query from `API` side.

**Note : base is a value from which position you need to start fetching values. limit is a value for how many rows you need to fetch.**

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2497689/3134215) for limit query in sqlite.
Refer [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html) for limit query in MySql.
Refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) for limit query in SQL.

Comment: you were right i as missing the limit and the base , however after testing someexamples i noticed my above code wont work because setOnScrollListener is depricated for recycler view. ill search for examples arround the web. do you have a recomanded example for recyclerview and loading on scroll ?